# ASP.NET master page error

Tags: c#, asp.net

The master page is getting called twice. Once after the full page is rendered. At this time isPostback value is false and SESSION is null.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //SOME CODE

        try
        {
            strUserId = Session[USERID].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

For the first page load of master page (before rendering of page) everything is fine. After rendering again page_load of master page is called. This time accessing SESSION is giving an exception:

> HttpException (Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>` section in the application configuration.).

I dont have any problem if page_load is getting called twice or thrice. I just dont want to access SESSION on second page load.

**EDIT 2**

The second master page load is happening because of this code which i've overseen earlier (present Global.asax file)

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {         
       Server.Transfer("~/ErrorMessage.aspx");
    }
```

The ErrorMessage.aspx page is the child page of master page :(

But still the answered question is why is the Application_Error() being generated even on successful rendering of pages? I tried to keep a break point at Application_Error() and event args is empty every time.

Comment: What do you mean by "master page is getting called twice"? How are you getting to this conclusion?

Comment: You're going to need way more than this.  Please post the code-behind for your MasterPage as well as the child page in question so we can get a better picture of what you're talking about.

Comment: @Andre Calil: I kept a break point at page load of master page. It is getting called before rendering of page then after rendering of page.

Comment: Do you have any AJAX-enabled controller at the child page? Does it happen to every child page?

Comment: It is happening for every page. Even which are having a simple textboxs and buttons

Comment: Does `error.aspx` also use the same MasterPage?

Comment: @ Mike C: No it doesn't. It just contains some image and text

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code to your `Web.config` file - you may have to graft it in because I don't know what it currently looks like. You can reference this [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1499512.aspx/1) to see the entire conversation and conditions.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
         <!-- UrlRewriter code here -->
         <remove name="Session" />
         <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

## Edit 1

The issue is very likely surrounding the fact that you're trying to wire up the event handler in the `ASPX` page of the master page. This has always caused issues surrounding things like accessing `Session` or even `Application` variables. So, please try the following:

1. Remove the marked up event handler from the `ASPX` file.
2. In the constructor of the master page place the following code.

**Constructor Code**

```
public MasterPage()
{
    this.Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
}
```

And then run the code you've been running in the same handler.

## Edit 2

Check your `Web.config` and see if it has the following section setup properly.

```
<system.web>
    <pages enableSessionState="true" />
    ...
</system.web
```

Comment: Added your code but still the same thing is happening. Can you suggest a way to detect that the master pageload is being called second time. So that i wont access SESSION at second load which will help to avoid exception

Comment: @Rajneesh - What page is this handler hooked up on? Edit the question to show the event handler addition and which page it exists on.

Comment: @ Mike - The event handler exists on MasterPage.aspx.cs file. The AutoEventWireup="true" is set in MasterPage.aspx. I hope info this answers your question

Comment: @Rajneesh - that is likely your problem. I'm going to edit my post to show you another code block.

Comment: @ Mike - I've made the change, I have removed  AutoEventWireup="true" in MasterPage.aspx and added your code in MasterPage class in  MasterPage.aspx.cs. Still the same error persists :(

Comment: @Rajneesh - take a look at my edit and let me know what you find out. I know it's working sometimes but I just want to cover all bases.

Comment: @ Mike Thanks for your help. I have found reason for my problem. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the reason for the problem, after going through the requests in firebug. Some ajax requests were there for two .gif files which were not present. So, the Application_Error() in the Global.asax was called. The exception generated there was "File not found". Then there was a Server.Transfer("~/ErrorMessage.aspx") in Application_Error(). Unfortunately ErrorMessage.aspx was child page of the master page. So, on every page the AJAX requests were made which caused "File not found" exception and then it was transfered to ErrorMessage.aspx, it was looking like master page page_load was called twice.

Comment: @Rajnessh - good find, I have experienced that before as well. It's most prevalent in IE in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The error description tells you to check the settings for using `Session`. Have you checked that setting (`enableSessionState`)?

Also, check that `error.aspx` doesn't use the master page until you know it works better, else you could get some strange errors...